# How to pass int and int* into function to define variable

Tags: c++, function, c++11, pointers

I have an int variable and a int pointer variable that I'm suppose to pass into a function that can set both variables to equal a number. My understanding is that I only need to change the `setint(b, 20);` line of code to fix this issue

I have been trying to add `&` and `*` in front of the `b` variable, but it caused the file not to compile.

```
void setint(int* ip, int i)
{
  *ip = i;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a = -1;
  int *b = NULL;

  setint(&a, 10);
  cout << a << endl;
  setint(b, 20);
  cout << b << endl;
```

The result of this code should output:

```
10
20
```

currently the output is:

```
10
segment fault
```

Comment: You're getting the `segmentation fault` when you try to dereference the `b` pointer, because `b` is a NULL pointer (i.e. `b` is pointing to `NULL` rather than to a valid memory location) and you're not allowed to deference NULL pointers.  Try replacing `int *b = NULL;` with something like `int x; int *b = &x;` and you'll get a more satisfying result.

Comment: Also you probably want to replace `cout << b << endl;` with `cout << *b << endl;`, otherwise you'll see printed the value of the pointer itself (i.e. the hexadecimal memory-address that `b` is pointing at) rather than the `int` value stored at that address (i.e. 20)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I noticed your comments after posting my answer. Why didn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does/attempts/fails to do (see the added comments):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a = -1;    // define and init an int variable, fine
  int *b = NULL; // define and init a pointer to int, albeit to NULL, ...
                 // ... not immediatly a problem

  setint(&a, 10);    // give the address of variable to your function, fine
  cout << a << endl; // output, fine

  setint(b, 20);  // give the NULL pointer to the function, 
                  // which attempts to dereference it, segfault

  cout << b << endl;
```

What might achieve what you intend (at least it achieves what I think you want...):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a = -1;
  int *b = &a; // changed to init with address of existing variable

  setint(&a, 10);
  cout << a << endl;
  setint(b, 20);      // now gives dereferencable address of existing variable
  cout << *b << endl; // output what is pointed to by the non-NULL pointer
```

By the way, if you output `a` again afterwards, it will show the value set to it via pointer, i.e. 20, which overwrote the previously written value of 10.

Comment: You could also initialize `b` with `b = new int(4);` but then you have to be sure to call `delete b;` when you are done with it.

Comment: @JonathonK Yep, could. By opted for the least complex and (in my opinion) most easily understandable way.

Answer (score 1):

```
void setint(int* ip, int i)
{
  if(ip != NULL) //< we should check for null to avoid segfault
  {
    *ip = i;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "!!attempt to set value via NULL pointer!!" << endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a = -1;
  int *b = NULL;

  setint(&a, 10);
  cout << a << endl;
  setint(b, 20);      //< should fail (b is currently NULL)
  // cout << *b << endl;

  b = &a; //< set pointer value to something other than NULL

  setint(b, 20);      //< should work
  cout << *b << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for b (a is already allocated by the compiler on the stack) with:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int *b = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: ... especially in C++. Compare Jonathans comment on my answer, including the need to free/delete.

Comment: All depend what you need to do. If you do b = &a then setint(b, 20) then a will be also set to 20.